# How to update react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently on version 0.45.1 which is pretty old. And I am trying to upgrade it so that other dependencies work as expected (they updated their libraries and they require 0.46.1 and above).

I am following this process:

- delete `node_module` folder
- change react-native version number in `package.json`
- run `yarn cache clean`
- run `watchman watch-del-all`
- run `yarn` so that dependencies get downloaded and linked
- restart packager
- reload app

App compiles and runs fine for `"react-native": "^0.45.1"`, but some dependencies don't behave right (and they require 0.46 and above).

- **Attempt to upgrade to 0.46.0:**
  I set react-native version number in `package.json` to `"react-native": "^0.46.0"`, and I follow the above process. I get this error:

> Unable to resolve module 'react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/native/ReactNativePropRegistry' from '/Users/MyUser/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/native-base/Components/Widgets/Button.js': Module does not exist in the module map

[image]

- **Attempt to upgrade to 0.47.0:**

I get same error as above.

- **Attempt to upgrade to 0.48.0 (newest RN version):**

I get same error as above.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates a version conflict. You need to change the version of the native base. Native base compatibility versions https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase#6-compatibility-versions

Comment: Hi, I [**modified**](https://ibb.co/kLEeuF) `package.json` to reflect your advice, but then I get a [**new error**](https://ibb.co/n9SPuF). But I think you are right. Any advice?

Comment: Okay, you need to update all the libraries in your dependencies, so there would be no conflicts.

Comment: how do I know which error is for which library? For example, in this new error, I read `root-siblings` and `EventEmitter`, but nowhere in my `package.json` I have such libraries. Please and thanks

Comment: https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-root-siblings
I suppose you have this library in dependencies. Unfortunately, it has been updated a long time ago, and I doubt that without manual changes it can be launched together with a new react native.

Comment: I found it in my [**`yarn.lock`**](https://ibb.co/gkCtMv) file and it is v1.2.1. But on the link you provided me, it says `latest release is 1.0.4` :/ weird ! And everytime I delete the file and run `yarn` to reload it, it downloads `root-siblings v1.2.1` automatically (a dependency to other dependency)